# How to fix ADB logcat error?

Tags: adb, logging

I want to save logs contains to file:
adb -s xxxxxx logcat -b main > /paths/to/log/file.log

> /system/bin/sh: can't create /home/dpi/Desktop/Folder/main.log: No
>   such file or directory

Comment: What operating system are you using on your computer?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04. I write an app that calls the process "adb ...."

Comment: I believe your format might be off on the adb command. On linux after the                                                     
                                                                                     > ~/Desktop/Folder/main.log where as windows is                                                            
> %userprofile%\desktop\logcat.txt as far far as coding I do not know if there is a universal one but adb commands I am familiar with.

Comment: I tried with gnome-terminal "adb -s e15a154d logcat -b main > /home/dpi/Desktop/Folder/main.log". This is OK, but in my app got this error.

Comment: As for coding your app the sister site might be a better place to ask this question https://stackoverflow.com there is this though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807689/catch-logcat-programmatically-or-export-it-to-file

Comment: What happens if you try to pull the logs through a shell instead. Something like adb -s e15a154d shell logcat -b main > /home/dpi/Desktop/Folder/main.log

Comment: the problem is /system/bin/sh, shell is called from android phone instead of OS

Comment: I resolved this problem. tks so much!